# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The view is not associated with BottomSheetBehavior

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I know this have been asked before but even though I checked the answers I don't found any solution to my specific problem:

I create a layout that is expected to act as a bottomsheet:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/btmsht"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height= "300dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_principal">
```

I use it in the coordinator layout:

```
<include layout="@layout/btmsht_principal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

But whe I try to get the reference with:

```
View tview = findViewById(R.id.btmsht);
    btmsht = BottomSheetBehavior.from(tview);
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The view is not associated with BottomSheetBehavior
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The view is not associated with BottomSheetBehavior
        at android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior.from(BottomSheetBehavior.java:816)
        at com.blixter.fiesta.Principal.creacionViews(Principal.java:69)
        at com.blixter.fiesta.Principal.onCreate(Principal.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Is not duplicated because mine is not nested and is a direct child of Coordinator Layout

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've solved it, and I want to post the answer in case someone else has the same problem, when you import the layout that contains the BottomSheet you must not include `layout_width` and `layout_height`:

```
<include layout="@layout/btmsht_principal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

so it has to be:

```
<include layout="@layout/btmsht_principal"/>
```

Comment: Any reason why not to add android:layout_height and android:layout_width in <include> tag?

Comment: I think, you could use the width and height as it says in the docs: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html, but you must override all the layout parameters, i haven't tested this but is worth trying, when you don't override everything, it fails.

Comment: ok...what I understood from the question is... ConstraintLayout requires directly associated child then and then it will work otherwise it will give above error.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue because, it had a direct child's beside's the included layout when I had the problem, i'm guessing  your are talking about another similar situation, but im glad you shared your knowledge with us.

Answer (score 2):

In Bottom sheet main content use:

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

In Main activity use with include layout
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"

Your problem solved

Answer (score 0):

The CoordinatorLayout always needs a directly associated child then and then only it will work otherwise it will through error "The view is not associated with BottomSheetBehavior". In the below .xml file second relative layout is the direct child to the CoordinatorLayout and that's the bottom sheet. In  tag we can add android:layout_width and  android:layout_height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/rooms_background_txt"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_listing"
            layout="@layout/actionbar_room_selection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_white"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, the solutions above didn't solve it.  I found that I had to duplicate the `app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"` on the `<include>` tag, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/ll_poi_view"
        layout="@layout/ll_poi_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is layout/ll_poi_view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="This area is for header content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/poi_content_scrollview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/poi_content_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headerTextView">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/poi_content"
            layout="@layout/ll_poi_view_scrollable_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Main activity to call the bottom sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".INT.InternalAssessment"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/internal_marks"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="monospace" />

            <include layout="@layout/recycle_view_internal_assessment_cards" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <include
            layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_detail_view_internal_assessment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="340dp"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"/>

        <!--<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/sem_recycle"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent" />-->

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> Bottom sheet with conetnt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/subject" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/_1st_semister" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/_2nd_semister" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView15"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView14"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="TextView" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView22"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView16"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="TextView" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="63dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView24"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView23"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="TextView" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```